# container liner for easy cleaning when mixing concrete

Tags: concrete

Whether its a wheelbarrow or a 5 gallon bucket, is it okay to use a liner?

For example, put liner in container, mix concrete, pour concrete, pull out liner, dispose liner, squeaky clean wheelbarrow/bucket remains. If it is okay, what should I use as a liner?

Comment: I don't see why there would be a problem if you wash the wheelbarrow right after mixing concrete

Comment: In fact contractors have been washing their wheelbarrows out for generations.

Answer (score 3):

What kind of liner do you propose to use? Seems to me that any liner that I can think of would rip easily with the rigor of mixing the concrete.

I have used one of those heavy duty wheelbarrows that has a plastic tub on it for mixing concrete. It was surprisingly easy to wash out as compared to a metal wheel barrow.

Comment: Indeed, I can't imagine the liner staying in place and not getting mixed in with the cement.

Answer (score 2):

Spray container with a quick shot of wd40 works like a charm and my fathers been doing it for 30+ years he also sprays his trowels.

Comment: I'm assuming this wouldn't cause any side effects?

Comment: I do something similar except I spray the wd on a towel and wipe it down to avoid puddling and the wd getting into the mixture.  Shouldn't matter though.